# Strange behaviour of MariaDB when using LIMIT in combination with UNION

Tags: mysql, union, limit, mariadb

```
SELECT `foo` 
FROM `table`
WHERE `bar` = 'def'
LIMIT 1500;
```

... returns 1500 rows for the condition (def).

```
(SELECT `foo` 
FROM `table`
WHERE `bar` = 'abc'
LIMIT 1000)
UNION
(SELECT `foo` 
FROM `table`
WHERE `bar` = 'def'
LIMIT 1500)
```

... returns 2498 rows, 1498 for the second condition (def).

So as you can see by the output of the first query, there definitely are enough records for condition "def" to return 1500 rows. Nevertheless, there are too few records returned for that condition when used in combination with UNION.

Does anyone have a pointer for me to track down this behaviour?

Comment: I'll bet you will see them if you `SELECT bar, foo` instead of just `SELECT foo` (in both parts).  Then you will see what happened to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows  could be reduced  because UNION select only distinct result  ..but you can use UNION ALL for get all the result form both select included  also rows  witn same values

```
(SELECT `foo` 
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `bar` = 'abc'
 LIMIT 1000)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT `foo` 
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `bar` = 'def'
 LIMIT 1500)
```

Comment: Even if there were duplicates: The table holds more than 10 times the LIMIT I set in that query. So if the UNION removes duplicates, there are still more than enough records left to fill the LIMIT.

Comment: This would mean that the subquery is first limited, and THEN grouped? Would there be a way to turn this around, in order to get the exact number of records defined by the LIMIT, AND have all of them be unique?

Comment: If you  use select between  () as  in your case then first the query is performed as  is  (select and limit) then UNITED   (grouped  in sql is reffered  to group by ) and UNION  .. remove duplicated  rows  UNION ALL  don't remove duplicated  rows.